# How to sort a list alphabetically by the second word in a string

Tags: python, list, sorting

If I have a list and I want to keep adding lines to it and sorting them alphabetically by their last name, how could this be done?
Sorted only seems to rearrange them by the first letter of the string.

```
    line = "James Edward"   #Example line
    linesList.append("".join(line))   #Add it to a list
    linesList = sorted(linesList)   #Sort alphabetically
```

Answer (score 13):

```
linesList.sort(key=lambda s: s.split()[1])
```

More info: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Answer (score 5):

If you want fully correct alphabetization (sorted by first name when the last name is the same), you can take advantage of the fact that Python sorting is stable.  If you first sort by the default key:

```
lst.sort()
```

and then sort by last name:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda n: n.split()[1])
```

then the entries with the same last name will wind up in the same order that the first `sort` put them in - which will be correct.

You can also do this all at once with `sorted`:

```
linesList = sorted(sorted(linesList), key=lambda n: n.split()[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names are in the format `FirstName<whitespace>LastName`, you can use the [`key`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#key-function) parameter of `sorted`:

```
>>> lst = ['Bob D', 'Bob A', 'Bob C', 'Bob B']
>>> lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.split()[1])
>>> lst
['Bob A', 'Bob B', 'Bob C', 'Bob D']
>>>
```

---

The same principle applies to `list.sort`:

```
>>> lst = ['Bob D', 'Bob A', 'Bob C', 'Bob B']
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x: x.split()[1])
>>> lst
['Bob A', 'Bob B', 'Bob C', 'Bob D']
>>>
```

Also, if you want them, here is a reference on [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) and one on [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 0):

In case you have `three` or `n` names and you want to sort it always by the last part of the name you can do:

```
names = ["John Mc Karter", "John Oliver", "Max Raiden", "Naruto Ho Uzumaki"]
print(names.sort(key=lambda x:x.split()[-1]))
>>>['John Mc Karter', 'John Oliver', 'Max Raiden', 'Naruto Ho Uzumaki']
```