# Using Python how to sort lines alphabetically, by the nth character from the left in the line?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I am writing a program that takes input from a file, appends a prefix and a suffix to each line, then writes the completed line to an output file. Then, the program takes input from the output files (3 of them), combines the lines and outputs that result into a "final" output file.

I am looking to see how I can then alphabetize the "final" output file to be organized by the 9th character from the left. The first 8 characters are all the same, so doing something like

```
newLines.sort()
```

won't work. Also, I can't sort any of the files individually, as the first file is first names, second file is last names, and third file is age. If I sort them individually, I will get the first and last names mixed up.

I have seen many questions answered using sort keys and lambda code, but I haven't been able to find documentation that explains it.

For instance, it seems like this line would work for me from [this search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459982/how-to-sort-a-list-alphabetically-by-the-second-word-in-a-string) :

```
(key=lambda s: s.split()[1])
```

but I don't understand what the "s" is, nor the "[1]". So, I'm not sure how to use this line to target the 9th character in the line. Also, it seems their input has a space, mine does not.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
##-- Combine files --##
    finalDest = open(r'[final output location]', 'wb')
    firstColumn = open(r'[file 1 location]', 'rb')
    secondColumn = open(r'[file 2 location]', 'rb')
    thirdColumn = open(r'[file 3 location]', 'rb')
    for line in firstColumn.readlines():
        finalDest.write(line.strip(b'\r\n') + secondColumn.readline().strip(b'\r\n') + thirdColumn.readline().strip(b'\r\n') + b'\r\n')
    firstColumn.close()
    secondColumn.close()
    thirdColumn.close()
    finalDest.close()
```

Here is an example from the "final" output:

```
<tr><td>Becky</td><td>Morgan</td><td>W 40-49</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kevin</td><td>Miller</td><td>M 20-29</td></tr>
<tr><td>Carol</td><td>Wilson</td><td>W 50-59</td></tr>
<tr><td>Joshua</td><td>Wilson</td><td>M 20-29</td></tr>
```

I would like that to be sorted to this:

```
<tr><td>Becky</td><td>Morgan</td><td>W 40-49</td></tr>
<tr><td>Carol</td><td>Wilson</td><td>W 50-59</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kevin</td><td>Miller</td><td>M 20-29</td></tr>
<tr><td>Joshua</td><td>Wilson</td><td>M 20-29</td></tr>
```

Based on the recommendation of @kabanus, I have adjusted my code to be the following:

```
        ##-- Combine files --##
    myLines = []
    finalDest = open(r'[final-output location]', 'wb')
    firstColumn = open(r'[file 1 location]', 'rb')
    secondColumn = open(r'[file 2 location]', 'rb')
    thirdColumn = open(r'[file 3 location]', 'rb')
    for line in firstColumn.readlines():
        myLines.append(line.strip(b'\r\n') + secondColumn.readline().strip(b'\r\n') + thirdColumn.readline().strip(b'\r\n') + b'\r\n')
        finalDest.write(b'\r\n'.join(myLines.sort())

    firstColumn.close()
    secondColumn.close()
    thirdColumn.close()
    finalDest.close()
```

However, I am now getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[program location]", line 56, in <module>
finalDest.write(b'\r\n'.join(myLines.sort()))
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Comment: "The first 8 characters are all the same" - this means the sort will rely on the 9th character, which is what you want. What's the problem?

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for the clarification, however the line:

    finalDest.sort()

gives an error:

"AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'sort'"

Comment: That's something different, edit your question properly, and paste the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file object has no 'sort' method, and by the time you called sort the lines are already written. First collect your lines:

```
mylines = []
for line in firstColumn.readlines():
        mylines.append(line.strip(b'\r\n') + secondColumn.readline().strip(b'\r\n') + thirdColumn.readline().strip(b'\r\n')))
```

Now you can sort and write it:

```
finalDest.write("\r\n".join(sorted(mylines)))
finalDest.close()
```

Comment: I can understand this answer, and have tried what you recommend, but I get "TypeError: can only join an iterable" on the:

`finalDest.write(b'\r\n'.join(myLines.sort())`

Line

Comment: @aarmfield my bad, used the wrong syntax, fixed now.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should read all the lines from the three input files (use `f.readlines`). You then `zip` the three lists of lines, giving you a list of tuples.

Sort that list however you want (if you use the default sort, you'll probably get what you want), then write each tuple to the output file as a line.